# Different Coloring of Julia Sets

Tags: fractals, complex-dynamics

I have known about Julia Sets for a while now, and today I had an idea about the coloring of Julia and Mandelbrot Sets. What if someone were to color them not only by how quickly z diverges, but also how quickly it converges. How would I go about doing this in a program? Has it already been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, just is exactly how WolframAlpha colors its Julia sets. Here's the result of the query "julia set -1", after the image type is set to escape time:

[image]

Furthermore, this is really the *only* way to go when drawing Julia sets for rational functions. Here's the Julia set of $z^{-2}-1$:

[image]

Finally, Newton's method pictures, with the different basins of attractions shaded in different colors are generated this way.

Answer (score 2):

First because ["... a single algorithm for computing all quadratic Julia sets does not exist."](https://arxiv.org/abs/math.DS/0610340) (Mark Braverman, Michael Yampolsky)
one have to find what type of [dynamics ( inside Julia set)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/julia) has.

Then one can use :

- [attraction time](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/Julia_set#Basin_of_attraction_of_finite_attractor_.3D_interior_of_filled-in_Julia_set), [Koenigs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/Koenigs_coordinate) or Boettcher coordinate
- [Siegel disc coloring](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/Koenigs_coordinate)
- [Cauchy Convergence Algorithm (CCA)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer:Georg-Johann/Mathematik#Visualising_Julia_sets)
- ....

[image: like here - parabolic dynamics]